# DRF Set OneToOneField to currently logged in user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model which has a OneToOneField like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """A Class to represent a Customer in  System """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

The serializer for which looks like this:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A Serizlier class for customer """

    class Meta:
        model = models.Customer
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'gender')
```

Right now the browsable api shows a dropdown list for user

[image]

how can I set `user` to currently logged in user in `CustomerSerializer` and make it read_only ? i.e the field should not be a passable parameter to the endpoint and instead should be a read only field corresponding to currently logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should set the **`user`** to a [**`read_only`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only) field. By doing so, you ***can't alter the value from API***. This can be done by specifying **`read_only=True`** in the field **OR** done by adding the [**`read_only_fields`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) in the serializer's Meta class.

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A Serizlier class for customer """

    class Meta:
        model = models.Customer
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'gender')
        read_only_fields = ('user',)
```

**Thus, DRF won't accept any input to the `user` field from your JSON payload that you are POSTing.**

---

### Then, How can we pass the logged-in user value while `Customer` instance creation?

I assume that you are using **`ModelViewset`** view, so that it will pass the `request` object and `view` object to the corresponding serializer. In serializer we can access the *context data* by **`context`** class variable of the serializer.
So, override the **`create()`** method of **`CustomerSerializer`** as below (I'm adding the complete config of the serializer bellow)

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A Serizlier class for customer """

    class Meta:
        model = models.Customer
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'gender')
        read_only_fields = ('user',) # added <<<<

    def create(self, validated_data): # override this method <<<
        """
        Since the 'user' is a read_only field, the validated data doesn't contain it.
        """
        user = self.context['request'].user
        validated_data['user'] = user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: what if I am using CreateView

Comment: It doesn't matter which kind of view you are using. The only thing matter is , make available the `request` object in the serializer's context

Comment: I am doing exactly what you mentioned in this answer but it is giving me integrity error null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Thanks It was my mistake, I was using users instead of user

Comment: If you found this answer useful, don't hesitate to Upvote

Answer (score 0):

I would limit choices in viewset.

```
class MyViewset(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Customer.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding **get_fields(self)** of **CustomerSerializer**.
Passing Current request user and filter user quer

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['user', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        current_user = self.context['request'].user
        fields['user'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.filter(id=current_user.id))
        return fields
```